# Rotate the indices on a hexagon

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, rotation

I have hexagons made of little unit hexagons. Each hexagon has a [hex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_hexagonal_number) of unit hexagons. The first few are numbered like:

```
Size 1:
 0
```

```
Size 2:
  0 1
 2 3 4
  5 6
```

```
Size 3:
   0 1 2
  3 4 5 6
 7 8 9 A B
  C D E F
  101112
```

(Last one is in hexadecimal).

You can rotate this by multiples of 60 degrees to map each index onto a rotated index. This is them rotated 60 degrees clockwise.

```
Size 1:
 0
```

```
Size 2:
  2 0
 5 3 1
  6 4
```

```
Size 3:
   7 3 0
  C 8 4 1
10 D 9 5 2
 11 E A 6
  12 F B
```

My question is how? I have these two functions for the hex function and the reverse hex function:

```js
function hex(n) {
    return 3 * +n * (+n + 1) + 1;
}

function reverse_hex(n) {
  n = (+n - 1) / 3;
  var i = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
  // null if not a hex number
  return i * (i + 1) === n ? i : null;
}
```

I can easily do rotations of 0 degrees and 180 degrees. I can derive the other multiples of 60 degrees from just rotating by 60 degrees a few times.

```js
function rotate(index, direction, size) {
    // The unit of direction is 60 degrees. So "1" == rotate by 60 degrees.
    direction = ((+direction % 6) + 6) % 6;
    switch (direction) {
        case 0:
            return index;
        case 1:
            // Something?
            return transformed_index;
        case 2:
            return rotate(rotate(index, 1, size), 1, size);
        case 3:
            return hex(size) - index - 1;
        case 4:
            return rotate(rotate(index, 3, size), 1, size);
        case 5:
            return rotate(rotate(index, 3, size), 2, size);
        default:  // (NaN or +/-Infinity) % 6 is NaN
            return null;
    }
}
```

But I can't think of an algorithm to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to arrange the hex in rings, each ring as an array, from a ring of 1 then 6, and so on. To rotate you move from the top off each ring array to the bottom. So if you have an hex of size 4 then the outer ring moves 3 from the top of the outer ring to the bottom, then 2 from the next ring in, and so on.

This does make it tricky to get the indexing in 2D. You can solve this by creating a second array of rows. Each row is an array of indexes into the ring structure. Thus if you want the cell at row 2, 4th from left you lookup the array pos[2][4] to get the ring index. In the example I encoded the ring index so you only need one number to lookup the ring, and then position in the ring.

The example show a hex of size 5 created with numbering in from left to right then next row left to right. The the hex rotated 60deg.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const font = "arial";
const fontSize = 14;

function createHex(size) {
  // create object to hold a hexagon
  const hexagon = {
    count: 0,
    hex: [],
  };
  // do first two rows manualy
  if (size >= 1) {
    hexagon.hex.push([0]);
    hexagon.count += 1;
  }
  if (size >= 2) {
    hexagon.hex.push([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    hexagon.count += 6;
  }
  // keep adding rings until correct size
  for (var i = 3; i <= size; i++) {
    const ring = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < i * 2 + 2 + (i - 2) * 4; j++) {
      ring.push(j);
    }
    hexagon.hex.push(ring);
    hexagon.count += ring.length;
  }
  // get the max rign size to use as modulo for row column lookup
  hexagon.maxRingLen = size * 2 + 2 + (size - 2) * 4
  // create an array for row column lookup
  hexagon.pos = [];
  // pos to prevent the array from becoming a sparse array
  // create each row array and fill with dummy data
  for (var i = 0; i < size + size - 1; i++) {
    const row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < ((size + size - 1) - (Math.abs((size - 1) - i) - 1)) - 1; j++) {
      row.push(0); // add dummy data
    }
    hexagon.pos.push(row);
  }
  // this array contains row, column steps for the six ring sizes
  const steps = [1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1];
  // each ring starts at the top left and goes round clockwise
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    const ringIndex = size - 1 - i
    const ring = hexagon.hex[ringIndex];
    var x = size - 1 - ringIndex;
    var y = size - 1 - ringIndex;
    for (var j = 0; j < ring.length; j++) {
      // add the ring position index
      hexagon.pos[y][x] = ringIndex * hexagon.maxRingLen + j
      // find the next row column pos
      const side = Math.floor(j / ringIndex) * 2;
      x += steps[side];
      y += steps[side + 1];
    }
  }
  // now that we have the row column lookup you can
  // create the correct sequence of numbers in the hexagon
  // starting at top left moving from left to right all the way to the 
  // bottom right last number
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < hexagon.pos.length; i++) {
    const row = hexagon.pos[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
      const ringPos = row[j] % hexagon.maxRingLen;
      const ringIndex = Math.floor(row[j] / hexagon.maxRingLen);
      hexagon.hex[ringIndex][ringPos] = count++;
    }

  }
  return hexagon;
}
// rotates a hexagon 60deg
function rotateHex(hexagon) {
  const size = hexagon.hex.length;
  for (var i = 1; i < size; i++) { // from inner ring do each ring
    const ring = hexagon.hex[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      // move the top to bottom of ring array
      ring.unshift(ring.pop());
    }
  }
}

// just renders for testing.
function renderHex(hexagon, pos) {
  const steps = [1, 0, 0.5, 1, -0.5, 1, -1, 0, -0.5, -1, 0.5, -1]
  ctx.font = (fontSize-4) + "px " + font;
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  const size = hexagon.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    const ringIndex = size - 1 - i
    const ring = hexagon[ringIndex];
    var x = pos.x - (ringIndex * fontSize * 0.5);
    var y = pos.y - (ringIndex * fontSize);
    for (var j = 0; j < ring.length; j++) {
      ctx.fillText(ring[j].toString(36), x, y);
      const side = Math.floor(j / ringIndex) * 2;
      x += steps[side] * fontSize;
      y += steps[side + 1] * fontSize;

    }

  }
}

var h = createHex(5);
renderHex(h.hex, {
  x: canvas.width * (1 / 4),
  y: canvas.height * (2 / 4)
});
rotateHex(h);
renderHex(h.hex, {
  x: canvas.width * (3 / 4),
  y: canvas.height * (2 / 4)
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use trigonometry to calculate rotations in `O(1)` space. The method below is in relation to the centre; to use it, you may need to offset variables or possibly redefine the index concept.

For example:

```
// Return height, given number of units extending in a 60 deg angle
function h(units){
  return units * Math.sqrt(3) / 2;
}

// Return units extending in a 60 deg angle, given height
function u(height){
  return height * 2 / Math.sqrt(3);
}

// Return new x position and number of diagonal vertical units offset
// after rotating 'num_rotations' * 60 degrees counter-clockwise,
// given horizontal position and vertical unit. 
// (All in relation to the centre.)

/* For example, 'rotate(3,1,1)', 
   where 'S' would be the starting position, '1' the ending position after
   one rotation, '2' the ending position after two rotations, '3' the ending
   position after three rotations, and 'C' the centre.

    * * * * *
   * * * 1 * *
  * 2 * * * * *
 * * * * * * S *
* * * * C * * * *
 * 3 * * * * * *
  * * * * * * *
   * * * * * *
    * * * * *
*/

function rotate(ring, vertical_units, num_rotations){
  let x = ring * 2,
      y = h(vertical_units * 2),
      _x = x - y/2,
      r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(_x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2)),
      theta = Math.atan2(y, _x),
      new_x = r * Math.cos(theta + num_rotations * Math.PI / 3),
      new_y = r * Math.sin(theta + num_rotations * Math.PI / 3),
      new_x_pos = Math.round(new_x) / 2,
      new_vertical_units = Math.round(u(new_y)) / 2;

  return {starting_x_pos: ring,
          starting_vertical_units: vertical_units,
          rotate: num_rotations * 60 + ' degrees',
          new_x_pos: new_x_pos,
          new_vertical_units: new_vertical_units};
}
```

Results:

```
var result1 = rotate(3,1,1);
for (var i in result1)
  console.log(i + ': ' + result1[i]);

console.log('')

var result2 = rotate(3,1,2);
for (var i in result2)
  console.log(i + ': ' + result2[i]);

console.log('')

var result3 = rotate(3,1,3);
for (var i in result3)
  console.log(i + ': ' + result3[i]);

/*
starting_x_pos: 3
starting_vertical_units: 1
rotate: 60 degrees
new_x_pos: 0.5
new_vertical_units: 3

starting_x_pos: 3
starting_vertical_units: 1
rotate: 120 degrees
new_x_pos: -2
new_vertical_units: 2

starting_x_pos: 3
starting_vertical_units: 1
rotate: 180 degrees
new_x_pos: -2.5
new_vertical_units: -1
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function rotatepos(rotations,size){
 size=1 /*the size of resolve */ -size;
 return function(x,y){
  for(var i=0;i<rotations;i++){
   var resolve=[
       [[0,1],[1,2]],
   [[0,0],[1,1],[2,1]],//thats just working for size 1, may extend this
      [[1,0],[2,0]]
   ];

   [x,y]= resolve[x+size][y+size];
   x-=size;
   y-=size;
  }
 return [x,y];
}
```

So you can do:

```
var rotator=rotatepos(1,1);
var [x,y]=rotator(1,1);//1,1 as the middle one does not change its position.
```

To rotate a 2D array with your hexagon:

```
var rotator=rotatepos(1,arr[0].length-1);
var rotated=arr.reduce(function(newone,inner,x){
 inner.forEach(function(v,y){
   var [newx,newy]=rotator(x,y);
   (newone[newx]=newone[newx]||[])[newy]=v;
  });
  return newone
  },[]);
```

I admit that this isnt the elegantest solution... ( as it requires you to build up a lookuptable for the maximim hexagon size)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:
Size 0 looks like this:

```
[1]
```

So howeger we rotate, the result is:

```
[1]
```

Size 1 looks like this:

```
  [1,2]
[6,X,3]
 [5,4]
```

We can rotate the outer values by creating an array and shifting them:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]=>[6,1,2,3,4,5]
```

And reassigning them to our hexagon. The X can simply be passed into a *hexagon size 0* resolver. This can be stacked, so our solution for size *n* is finished:

```
function rotate(rows,rotations){
 if(rows.length==1) return rows;//the size 0 resolver
var sidelength=rows[0].length-1;
var splitting=sidelength*rotations;
 var inner=[];
 var around=rows[0];
 var leftside=[];
 for(var y=1;y<rows.length-1;y++){
   var row=rows[y];
   leftside.push(row[0]);
   around.push(row[row.length-1]);
   inner.push(row.slice(1,row.length-1));
 }
around=around.concat(rows[rows.length-1]).concat(leftside.reverse());
inner=rotate(inner,rotations);
around.unshift(...around.splice(around.length-splitting));
//reassemble
inner.unshift(around.splice(0,sidelength-1));
for(var y=0;y<inner.length;y++){
  inner[y].unshift(around.pop());
  inner[y].push(around.shift(1));
}
inner=inner.concat([around]);
return inner;
}
```

Live example:
http://jsbin.com/dalapocelo/edit?console (size 1)
http://jsbin.com/zabewopuze/1/edit?console (size 2)